# Why brunch compile everything it found when using function in joinTo

Tags: configuration, brunch

I don't understand why BrunchJS compile all files (in bower_components) when i use a function like this (CoffeeScript):

```
modules = ['i18n', 'pager', 'core', 'module-comment']

javascripts:
  joinTo: 
    # Main
    '/js/master.js': () ->
      paths = ['bower_components/bootstrap/**/*', 'app/**/*']
        for o in modules 
        fs.exists '../../../../workbench/dynamix/' + o, (exists) ->
          if exists
            paths.push '../../../../workbench/dynamix/' + o + '/public/public/**/*'
          else
            paths.push '../../../../vendor/dynamix/' + o + '/public/public/**/*'
      return paths
```

I want to test if some path exist, if yes put the complete path in a variable to return it to joinTo. I have successfuly get files in workbench/vendor but it get some undesired files from bower_components (don't specified?!)

I would like to optimize this :

```
javascripts:
  joinTo: 
    # Main
    '/js/master.js':   
      'bower_components/bootstrap/**/*'
      '../../../../workbench/dynamix/i18n/public/public/**/*'
      '../../../../workbench/dynamix/pager/public/public/**/*'
      '../../../../vendor/dynamix/core/public/public/**/*'
      '../../../../workbench/dynamix/module-comment/public/public/**/*'
      '../../../../workbench/dynamix/module-love-live-music/public/public/**/*'
      '../../../../workbench/dynamix/module-rating/public/public/**/*'
      '../../../../workbench/dynamix/module-registration/public/public/**/*'
      'app/**/*'
```

I'm sorry i didn't find documentation to use function in joinTo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function in a `joinTo` should take a file path as an argument and return `true` if the path should be included, `false` if not. This is described in the anymatch documentation.

Your function appears to always return a truthy value, meaning every path Brunch is watching will be included.

What you might have intended to do is use an IIFE, so the return value of the function (invoked during initial code evaluation) gets assigned to the `joinTo`. In coffeescript you can accomplish this easily using the `do` keyword, so instead of starting off your function definition with `() ->` it'd be `do ->` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time and your answer.

I make the function to get files and test if the path exists and it work fine.

If this could help someone, I let my magic function here

```
javascripts:
  joinTo: 
    # Main
    '/js/master.js': [
      'bower_components/bootstrap/**/*'
      'bower_components/unveil/**/*'
      'app/**/*'
      (string) ->
        response = false
        modules = ['i18n', 'pager', 'core', 'module-comment']
        for o in modules
          exists = fs.existsSync unixify('../../../../workbench/dynamix/' + o)
          if exists
            if unixify(string).indexOf(unixify('../../../../workbench/dynamix/' + o + '/public/public/')) != -1
              response = true
          else
            if unixify(string).indexOf(unixify('../../../../vendor/dynamix/' + o + '/public/public/')) != -1
              response = true
        return response
    ]
```